# How can I setup a DNS A record on CloudFlare for a Heroku website?

Tags: dns, heroku

I bought a new domain and I'm try to setup the DNS records at CloudFlare so the new domain will point to Heroku. My website is hosted at Heroku. Where can I find the ipv4 address of my website? My website is treegrafting.herokuapp.com my new domain is mpoliasma.top

[image]

Comment: Your hosting provider can give you the IP of your site. In your case heroku.com. Give them a call. If you have a cloud server [windows/ linux], you can get the IP from the bindings.

Comment: It sounds like you should be changing the 'A' drop down to 'CNAME' so you can put in 'treegrafting.herokuapp.com' instead of an IP address.